# WPF customized TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a customized TextBox named "txtAddress" which contains `Image` and `TextBox`.
I need to be able to access its contents : `txtAddress.Text` `txtAddress.Image`
I've Bound the `inner textBox.text` with the `Template.Text` and `inner rect.Fill` with `Template.Background` (I'm using rectangular now, i will change it to image)

[image]

when I run the program and edit the textBox everything looks like its working and the text is changing, but when i use it from the code `txtAddress.Text` is still "my computer" which is the **initial value** of the TextBox.
I know that because i didn't put `<ContentPresenter>` somewhere in the style but where should i put the controls(image,textbox), like in listView there is `<DataTemplate>` where we add the controls

**TxtAddress Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxAddressStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                        <Rectangle Height="Auto" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusY="11" RadiusX="11" Margin="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding OpacityMask}"/>
                        <!--<ContentPresenter Height="Auto" Margin="31,2,7.458,2"/>-->
                        <TextBox x:Name="TxtAddress" Height="Auto" Margin="31,2,7.458,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MaxLines="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" AcceptsTab="True" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle2}" SelectionBrush="#C859003D" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" AcceptsReturn="False"/>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#5AFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="6.375" Margin="6,2.25,6,0" RadiusY="6" RadiusX="6" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="ImgAddress" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="7,1,0,0" RadiusY="0" RadiusX="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" StrokeThickness="0">
                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Stroke>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

**Inner TextBox Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle2" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" FontSize="13.333" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

**TxtAddress :**

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Margin="34,5,32,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My Computer" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxAddressStyle}" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="BtnImg/computer.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
            <TextBox.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF779198" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF789399" Offset="0.93"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBFD3D7" Offset="0.513"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF343E41" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5C6E73"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBox.Foreground>
            <TextBox.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF94B5BD" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF94B5BD" Offset="0.93"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE7FBFF" Offset="0.513"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7B9399" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7B9399"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBox.OpacityMask>
        </TextBox>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you use it from code? Are you using MVVM? Does the Binding to your ViewModel work correctly?

Comment: The Binding works "half" correctly, i mean when i run the project the inner Text changes in graphic not in its content, so if i changed the text to "whatever", when i use it from code its still "my computer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're placing a `TextBox` inside the Template for another `TextBox`.

The visual tree will look like this:

```
TextBox
   Grid
      Rectangle 
      TextBox
      Rectangle 
      Rectangle
```

Which is not ideal in the first place, but if you want to keep things like that, just make sure you bind the inner TextBox's `Text` property to the outer one, via [`Two Way`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Data Binding like so:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtAddress" Text="{Binding Text, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay, 
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" ... />
```

---

In addition to all this, I already mentioned several times that you're NOT supposed to be manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF.

Instead, create a proper ViewModel to store your data:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

then use DataBinding to bind your TextBox to that data:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

And whenever you need to retrieve the value, retrieve the value from the VM, NOT the UI.

Comment: what do you think is ideal for this textBox? should i create userControl which contains the image and the textBox?

Comment: @MurHaf either that, or create your TextBox template by starting from the [Default one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061(v=vs.95).aspx), which already contains the relevant [Template Parts](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-part-names)

Comment: that what i did, i edit a copy then i deleted the chrome then i added the controls then i bound the innerText to template Text

Comment: can you show me how i can i do it with VM, im afraid to create unnecessary code, I'm trying to do like this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial , but as i can see in my situation i just need 1 static ExploreAddress (text,image) not a collection of ExploreAddress

Comment: @MurHaf that is a separate question of it's own, don't you think? post  a new question about that and let me know.

Comment: Can you see how I can solve this problem after we finished doing it with the `ViewModel` correctly