# WPF TextBox with ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement ViewModel for a customized textBox, this's my first time to do a ViewModel trying to do as [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

its a file explorer application there's only one `string address;` needed (not a collection) which hold the address for the customized TextBox "ExploreAddress".
this customized TextBox has text and image (icon for the current directory and it is not static)

[image]

```
public class ExploreAddressVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    private System.Windows.Media.ImageSource _image;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }
    public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>

    <l:ExploreAddressViewModel/>

</UserControl.DataContext>

<TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Margin="34,5,32,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
Text="{Binding Name}" Height="25"
VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
```

Is this an ideal solution to bind a ViewModel with a customized TextBox

Behind Code:

```
 private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        exploreAddress = (ExploreAddressViewModel)base.DataContext;
        exploreAddress.Text = "My Computer";
    }
    private void GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(txtAddress.Text); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm actually not sure why do I need to create a class of
>   ExploreAddress, maybe I could put it in the same
>   ExploreAddressViewModel class

You don't need to.

You have duplicated stuff in there, just remove that class.

Also, your property setters must raise the `PropertyChanged` event, like so:

```
public class ExploreAddressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set 
        { 
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private ImageSource _image;
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set 
        { 
             _image = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it this way, the TextBox is empty, i updated the question with behind code

Comment: @murhaf the textbox is bound against the `Name` property of the ViewModel, but your code is assigning the `Text` property. Which one is correct?

Comment: sorry i changed the property Name to Text but i didn't update it in the question, consider its still `Name`

Comment: @murhaf so have you changed that in XAML too?

Comment: @murhaf see the Visual Studio output window. WPF Binding errors can be found there.

Comment: they are not changing together, The thing that I didn't fix the previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614984/wpf-customized-textbox/20615303

Comment: @MurHaf ok, make sure your TextBox is running first, by setting it's text directly in XAML or in code behind, then when you have that running, add the ViewModel into the equation. Otherwise you'll get lost with all this. If the TextBox doesn't work by itself, post an update in the other question.

Comment: okay now I'm using a regular `TextBox` bounded to the `ExplorerAddressViewModel` Can you show me how to do it from the behind code

Comment: @murhaf I'm not sure. I got lost into the sea of changes that you made, and haven't posted. Update your question with the latest changes

Comment: this Worked perfectly with a regular textBox, just when I bound the it to the style in the previous question it stop working